# how can I get the filename of the source of an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've made a custom exception handler, and it works greatly for the most part.  Here's the gist of it-

app/errors/duck.rb

```
module Duck

  def Duck::ReportError(u,c,m,p)
    User.send_error_email(u,c,m,p)
    User.msg(m)
    end
  end
```

app/mailers/notifications.rb

```
def err_report(current_user,err_script,err_msg,err_scrub)
  @current_user = current_user
  @err_script = err_script
  @err_msg = err_msg
  @err_scrub =  err_scrub
  mail(:to => sr_dev, :cc => jr_dev, :subject => "Error Found")
end
```

And this is where my problem comes in-  the code above is as it is written currently.  There were some minor changes to eliminate repetition.  I would previously do my calls as follows- any error was handled like this example where this would be placed within all the actions in users_controller.rb...

```
rescue Exception => msg
  Duck.ReportError(current_user,"users_controller.rb",msg,"Dumping params: #{params.inspect}")
```

Any error must result in a duck call- thus the previous repetition.. which didn't accomplish this.  It also completely obliterates DRY, so I re-coded the duck.rb file and found that by placing it in the application controller, anything that inherits from ApplicationController could raise the duck like this-

```
rescue_from Exception, :with => :any_error

protected

def any_error(msg)
  Duck.ReportError(current_user,"application_controller.rb",msg,"Dumping params: #{params.inspect}")
  render "home/duck.erb"
end
```

The rest of the code is trivial to the issue at hand, which is this:
I need to show the dev team which file the error originated from.  When I first made the Duck, it was called from each action/view/controller directly, as previously shown, which was a lot of repetition, but had the benefit that I could tell it specifically which script generated the error.  Now I've somewhat abstracted the error handler, which is great- but every time an error comes in from, for example, reports_controller.rb, it reports the error as coming from application_controller.rb.  How can I fix this?  How do I get the actual source of the error?

System:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.20
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: check for the `msg.backtrace`

Comment: In many instances, msg.backtrace is blank.  Either there is another issue here, or this simply does not suffice to fix the issue.

Comment: @Salil - it turns out there was another error that was blocking msg.backtrace.  Your answer was correct (and actually solved this issue a long time ago...)  In addition, the following are great tools to use to trace the origin of an error: 

`request.env['action_controller.instance'].class`
`request.env['PATH_INFO']`
`request.env['REQUEST_URI']`